# Search by subject contains

Tags: support, search, user-interface

Sometimes I search for information on a keyword, but get results that aren't relevant, perhaps because the keyword is too common or has other meanings or several other reasons. My next step is often to sort by votes, however now I'll get results that use that keyword anywhere in the question or answer. Often, I know the relevant question would definitely contain the keyword in the subject.

**Is there a way to only get results where the subject contains the keyword(s) I'm searching for?**

If not, I'd like to request this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for `title:"whatever"`, e.g. `title:"search by subject"`:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%22search+by+subject%22

As noted in the ["How do I search?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) help page:

> To limit your search to just the title of a question, use `title:` followed by the search term.

The double quotes aren't strictly necessary unless you're searching for a multiple-word phrase.